# Regex for finding commas in a field of a JSON

Tags: json, regex

I want to create a regex that will help me find the commas that between the strings `"RecruiterEmails"` and `"SourcerEmails"` and that are between double quotes. The regex will find the comma and I will use the replace strategy to replace it with `\n`

This JSON as input

```json
[
  {
    "JobRefId": "Ref1",
    "RecruiterEmails": "john@gmail.com,carl@gmail.com,mario@gmail.com",
    "SourcerEmails": "robert@gmail.com,jim@gmail.com",
    "JobStatus": "On,Now"
  }
]
```

Should have this output after replacing the selected commas in `RecruiterEmails` with `\n`

```json
[
  {
    "JobRefId": "Ref1",
    "RecruiterEmails": "john@gmail.com\ncarl@gmail.com\nmario@gmail.com",
    "SourcerEmails": "robert@gmail.com,jim@gmail.com",
    "JobStatus": "On,Now"
  }
]
```

Please note that I do NOT want the comma that is end of the line (the one that separates the fields `RecruiterEmails` and `SourcerEmails`) and that I do NOT want the commas that separate the emails of `SourcerEmails`. All I want are the commas that separate the emails of `RecruiterEmails`.

The regex I have been able to draft so far captures all the characters in between `RecruiterEmails` and `SourcerEmails`, but I want only the specified commas.

This is the regex:

`"RecruiterEmails"([\S\s]*?)"SourcerEmails"`

I know that this can be done through a JOLT transformation, but the software I am using does not support JOLT transformations. The only possible way is to do it through a regex.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please provide the regex you've already tried ?

Comment: Why not a JSON parser?

Comment: Hi! It is `RecruiterEmails"([\S\s]*?)"SourcerEmails`, I have edited the question and added it to the body

Comment: I am using a framework of Apache that does not have a JSON parser, the only way to make the transformation is through a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look ahead to assert that you are on the line that precedes "SourcerEmails" with this regex:

```
,(?=.*",\s+"SourcerEmails")
```